# Why doesn't my date-validating regex recognize February (and others)?

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm working on a regex that's supposed to match month-day-year gregorian dates (in javascript), and it works fine for January, March, May, July, August, October, and December (31-day months) dates, but for some reason which I haven't been able to figure out, it will not match any date from any other month.

A little explanation of the code below: I've set it up to first match the month-day part of the date all at once, so it doesn't match on February 31st, for example. So, I currently have it matching (((a 31-day month) THEN (a non-alphanumeric character, captured) THEN (a day from 1 through 31)) OR ((a 28-day month) THEN (a non-alphanumeric character, captured) THEN (a day from 1 through 29)) OR ((a 30-day month) THEN (a non-alphanumeric character, captured) THEN (a day from 1 through 30))) THEN (the previously captured character) THEN (a past or current year AD).

I'm sure the problem is simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

```
^
(?:
  (?:
    (?:0?[13578]|1[02])
    ([^\dA-Za-z])
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])
  )
  |
  (?:
    (?:0?2)
    ([^\dA-Za-z])
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])
  )
  |
  (?:
    (?:0?[469]|11)
    ([^\dA-Za-z])
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)
  )
)
\1
(?:0{0,3}[1-9]|0{0,2}[1-9][0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[01])
$
```

Comment: And that, sir, is why you shouldn't try to validate dates with a regex.

Comment: What about Feb 29 in a year that is not a leap year?

Comment: I'm assuming you'll never maintain this or have anyone else maintain this, but if that's even a possibility I'd really recommend parsing the date first then checking the parsed information. Especially so you're having fun on new years eve rather than changing `201[01]` in your regex.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that regexes were a bad idea for dates, but the application is only going to be available for a short time this year, and my validation system uses only regexes and event objects for every single field. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you're using `\1`, which doesn't match for the last 2 alternations. `\1` refers to the *first* `([^\dA-Za-z])` - if it didn't match, it cannot get to the year.

A simple alternative is `(?:\1|\2|\3)`.

Another option is to add *at the start* of the pattern `(?=\d+([^\dA-Za-z]))`, and use `\1` on all places. For example:

```
^
(?=\d+([^\dA-Za-z]))   # capture the separator as \1
(?:
  (?:
    (?:0?[13578]|1[02])
    \1
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])
  )
  |
  (?:
    (?:0?2)
    \1
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])
  )
  |
  (?:
    (?:0?[469]|11)
    \1
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)
  )
)
\1
(?:0{0,3}[1-9]|0{0,2}[1-9][0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]{2}|1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[01])
$
```

On a side note: *yikes!* try [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) - an impressive open-source JavaScript date library.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that `\1` would give me the first matched capture, rather than the first attempted capture if it matched. So what other approach can I take in javascript to do this? Can I alternate `\1 | \2 | \3`?

Comment: @Eric - Yes, Tim and I have also suggested it. It is actually very basic - this is how captured groups work. It is worth noting that on some flavors, for example in PCRE, you can use `(?|(a)|(b)|(c))`, which will act as you expect, but JavaScript doesn't support that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `\1` backreference. It refers back to what the `([^\dA-Za-z])` group in your first alternation matches (31-day-months). To match the delimiter of the second alternation, you'd need `\2` etc.

So perhaps you might want to use `(?:\1|\2|\3)` instead of `\1`, unless that gives an error, too, in JavaScript.

Finally, you're aware that this still isn't validating dates correctly? Think about leap years...